# Custom function that get product reviews count in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, review

I'm trying to make a function  that get the count of product reviews in WooCommerce product page.

I need to use it in another function in a logical operation ... Can't figure out whats wrong.

```
function reviews_count() {
    $id = $product->get_id();
    $product = wc_get_product($id);
    $count = $product->get_review_count();
    return $count;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead *(for single product_pages)*:

```
function reviews_count() {
    global $product;

    if ( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
    }
    return $product->get_review_count();
}
```

Or you can also add the product Id as function argument *(to use it in another function)* like:

```
function reviews_count( $product_id ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

    return $product->get_review_count();
}
```

So in your other function, you will be able to pass the product Id a bit like:

```
function my_other_function() {
    global $product;

    $count = reviews_count( $product->get_id() );
}
```